# creating clean urls using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Helllo i have this page that has a dynamic table that consist of records of a recordset, i have displayed this records successfully, but on click on any item on my dynamic table it gives me an ugly url

localhost/sms/mem.php?id=8"

but i want to convert this url to something like this

localhost/sms/mem/8

i have read and tried to create clean urls,
 but it dosent seem to convert my url to a clean url automatically, this is wht i have tried using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ mem.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ mem.php?id=$1
```

am i doin something wrong, cause the way its been explained online it seems pretty simple

Comment: FYI, your two regexes could be simplified to `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$`. The last questionmark makes the character in front of it optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this **before your existing rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sms/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+sms/mem\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ mem/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^mem/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ mem.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This should be places in `/sms/.htaccess` file

Comment: hey seems to be having a little progress, but i come up with this error " http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/sms/mem/9" instead of http://localhost/sms/mem/9

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? Is it in `htdocs` OR `htdocs/sms`?

Comment: kkkk ill get back to u

Comment: luvly works like charm thanks, so can still implement this using the same snippet when i upload my files to a remote server.

Comment: yes definitely you can. If you run into any problem do come back to SO and we'll help you.

Comment: my intention is to make sure that my urls are not tampered with, how can i convert my url to something like this.                                              localhost/mem.html for every time the url is accessed instead of the localhost/mem/8

Comment: Oh that is a totally different question. Please don't start a new question via comments. Each thread is to serve one problem. If you want you can create a new question with that problem and I will try to answer.

Comment: now my form thats supposed to be used to update after clicking the link dosent submit anymore. any idea

Comment: Is form using POST method? What URL do you see in browser after form submit?

Comment: yes its using a post method, after submit its supposed to return to a page called members.php   this is wat my form tag looks like    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">

Comment: Updated rules to skip POST requests. Form will work fine now.