# Create a .htaccess file with the code for clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create clean url, so I tried many configurations.  I also created an .htaccess file but it does not work.  Anyone can help me?

My .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule single-post/id/(.*)/title/(.*)/ single-post.php?id=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule single-post/id/(.*)/title/(.*) single-post.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Present url

```
http://localhost/just2minute/story/single-post/id/2590/title/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B2%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6%20%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0%20%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%A1%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%87%2018%20%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%80%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%A4/
```

I want to create"

```
http://localhost/just2minute/story/single-post/id/(Any Value)/title/(Any Value)/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating clean urls using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234831/creating-clean-urls-using-htaccess)

Comment: I don't think you're right, common between both questions is only title.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two rules. You can achieve the goal using one rewrite rule, for example,

```
RewriteRule ^story/single-post/id/([0-9]+)/title/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ single-post.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

After that you can access with the URL like this

```
https://localhost/just2minute/story/single-post/id/51835322/title/create-a-htaccess-file-with-the-code-for-clean-url
```

Then you want to do something like explained in this article:

https://www.tinywebhut.com/remove-duplicate-urls-from-your-website-38